# Польская нотация: как реализовать отрицательные значения

Tags: java, postfix

Дали задание реализовать калькулятор считающий результат строки с арифметическим выражением. Поддерживает операторы *,/,+,-

Проблема возникла, когда я понял что он не считает отрицательные значения. А именно "-3" "-(2+3)". После некоторых костылей которые я вставил в код, он стал обрабатывать все отрицательные выражения, если в стеке остается один минус. Но есть еще случаи вроде "(-(-(1)))", где оператор никак не останется в стеке последним.

Посему прошу наставить меня на путь истинный и рассказать как можно решить эту задачу. Вот код:

```
public class CalculatorImpl {

    public CalculatorImpl() {
    }

    /**
     * <p>Checks is this character a space in statement</p>
     *
     * @param c current character
     * @return true, if character is delimiter
     */
    private static boolean isDelimiter(char c) { // тру если пробел
        return c == ' ';
    }

    /**
     * <p>Checks is this character is a operator sign</p>
     *
     * @param c current character
     * @return true, if character is an operator sign
     */
    private static boolean isOperator(char c) { // возвращяем тру если один из символов ниже
        return c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/';
    }

    /**
     * <p>Returns operator's priority level</p>
     *
     * @param operator is a operator for rate
     * @return the number of priority level
     */
    private static int priority(char operator) {
        switch (operator) { // при + или - возврат 1, при * / % 2 иначе -1
            case '+':
            case '-':
                return 1;
            case '*':
            case '/':
                return 2;
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }

    /**
     * <p>Performs one of supported arithmetic actions for pair of last elements in the stack</p>
     *
     * @param stack it's a stack of statement's digits
     * @param operator it's a one of supported arithmetic operator
     */
    private static void executeOperator(LinkedList<Double> stack, char operator) {
        if (stack.size()==1 && operator == '-'){
            System.out.println("Stack size is 1 now. So operator is " + operator + ". Last element is " + stack.get(0));
            String lastDouble = String.valueOf(operator)+String.valueOf(stack.removeLast());
            System.out.println("lastDouble = " + lastDouble);
            System.out.println(stack);
            stack.add(Double.parseDouble( lastDouble  ));
        } else {
            double last = 0;
            double penult = 0;

            if (stack.size() >= 2) {
                last = stack.removeLast(); // выдёргиваем из упорядоченного листа последний элемент
                penult = stack.removeLast(); // также
            }

            switch (operator) { // выполняем действие между penult и last в зависимости от оператора в кейсе и результат валим в stack
                case '+':
                    stack.add(penult + last);
                    System.out.println("penult + last was added: " + (penult + last) + ", where penult = " + penult + " and last = " + last);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    stack.add(penult - last);
                    System.out.println("penult - last was added: " + (penult - last) + ", where penult = " + penult + " and last = " + last);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    stack.add(penult * last);
                    System.out.println("penult * last was added: " + (penult * last) + ", where penult = " + penult + " and last = " + last);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    stack.add(penult / last);
                    System.out.println("penult / last was added: " + (penult / last) + ", where penult = " + penult + " and last = " + last);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * <p>Returns formatted value</p>
     *
     * @param num it is a double for change quantity of shown digits after delimiter
     * @return the formatted value as string
     */
    private static String toRound(double num){
        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
        formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(4);
        formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
        return formatter.format(num);
    }

    public String evaluate(String statement) {
        LinkedList<Double> digits = new LinkedList<>();
        LinkedList<Character> operators = new LinkedList<>();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < statement.length(); i++) {

            // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
             System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
             System.out.println(digits);
             System.out.println(operators);
             System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
             // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                char c = statement.charAt(i);

                if (isDelimiter(c)) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (c == '(') {
                    operators.add('(');
                } else if (c == ')') {
                    while (operators.getLast() != '(') {
                        executeOperator(digits, operators.removeLast());
                        // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                        System.out.println(digits);
                        System.out.println(operators);
                        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                        // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    }
                    operators.removeLast();
                    System.out.println("BRACKET HAS BEEN DELETED!");
                } else if (isOperator(c) ) { // добавил начиная c &&
                    while (!operators.isEmpty() && priority(operators.getLast()) >= priority(c)) {
                        executeOperator(digits, operators.removeLast());
                        // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                        System.out.println(digits);
                        System.out.println(operators);
                        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                        // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    }
                    operators.add(c);

                } else {
                    String operand = "";
                    while (i < statement.length() && (Character.isDigit(statement.charAt(i)) || statement.charAt(i) == '.')) {
                        operand += statement.charAt(i++);
                    }
                    --i;
                    digits.add(Double.parseDouble(operand));
                }
            }
            while (!operators.isEmpty()) {
                executeOperator(digits, operators.removeLast());
                // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(digits);
                System.out.println(operators);
                System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            }

        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return toRound(digits.get(0));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На этом уровне — никак.

Вы должны завести операцию «унарный минус» с одним операндом, и обрабатывать её соответственно. Различие унарного и бинарного минуса нужно делать на этапе синтаксического анализа (у вас это функция `evaluate`). Судя по всему, минус является унарным, если он идёт в начале либо следует за открывающей скобкой, запятой или бинарным оператором (и именем функции, если у вас разрешена бесскобочная запись типа sin *x*).

(Да, унарный и бинарный минус не получится кодировать одним и тем же кодом операции `'-'`, так что придётся, возможно, от символа перейти к `enum`'у.)

Ваш код execution engine (это у вас `executeOperator`) должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
// для операций и данных можно использовать общий стек
operator = stack.pop();
// или если у вас отдельный, то operators.pop()
switch (operator)
{
    case unaryMinus:
        stack.push(-stack.pop());
        break;
    case binaryMinus:
        stack.push(stack.pop()-stack.pop()); // не уверен насчёт порядка операндов
        break;
    case binaryPlus:
        stack.push(stack.pop()+stack.pop());
        break;
    ...
}
```

Кстати, почему вы не используете классический [shunting yard](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)?

Comment: Ну можно ещё вместо унарного минуса вычитать из нуля

Comment: @sercxjo: На самом деле, унарные операции всё равно нужно по уму поддерживать. Например, `sin` какой-нибудь. А чтобы вычитать из нуля, нужен ещё хак в виде вставки фиктивного нуля в стек.

Comment: Ну вообще да, но в задании то не просили. И что-то я с польской нотацией непонял, в ней приоритеты не нужны вообще, как и скобки.

Comment: на счет вычиать из нуля у меня тоже мысли были, но они наткнулись на такой пример:

3*-(...тут любое число операндов и операций...)

как здесь вычитание реализовать?

если реплейснуть "-" на "0-", то тройка обратится  в нуль. То есть нужно заменять на "(0-" но закрыть скобку мы не можем, т к неизвестно где это надо делать. Разве только когда выражение в скобках будет посчитано..

Comment: сейчас пытаюсь написать метод для введения в исходную строку знаков унарного минуса (у меня этот знак m):
Подскажите как написать regex для replacAll чтобы он менял именно сочетание "(-" ?. Вот так не получается:
        statement = statement.replaceAll("[(-]", "(m");

Comment: @АлександрДворцов и всё-таки где тут польская нотация?

Comment: @АлександрДворцов: я, честно говоря, не думаю, что регулярки — правильный метод для парсера. В конце ответа есть ссылка на известный алгоритм, который должен гарантировано работать.

Answer (score -1):

Я так понимаю, вы не пробовали реализовать это всё с помощью автоматов, выделяя определенныеслова, а потом лексическим анализом раскидывать это всё на отдельные операции? Это было юы проще и проблем с минусами не возникло бы. В случае 3*-(...) могу посоветовать одно - выводить ошибку о том, что   нет знака *-